# How to clip file into clipboard in electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

In my electron app, I want my user to clip file into system clipboard then they can paste the file
anywhere in the system.

However, after reading electron clipboard api, there is no way to clip file to the clipbaord.
I found [one example in c#](https://github.com/rostok/file2clip).

In this example, it calls the `Clipboard.SetDropFileList` API.

Is there any similar way for me to do cut/copy file into clipboard in nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { clipboard } from 'electron';

const path = 'path\\to\\file';

clipboard.writeBuffer(
  'FileNameW',
  Buffer.concat([Buffer.from(filePath, 'ucs-2'), Buffer.from([0, 0])])
);
```